# How can click on this specific element?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, click

I have python 3.10, selenium 4.3.0 and i would like to click on the following element:

```
<a href="#" onclick="fireLoginOrRegisterModalRequest('sign_in');ga('send', 'event', 'main_navigation', 'login', '1st_level');"> Mein Konto </a>
```

Unfortunately,
`driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a[onclick^='fireLoginOrRegisterModalRequest'][onclick*='login']").click()`
does not work. See the following error message. The other opportunities wont work as well and i get a simular error message..

```
"C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" "C:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/bot/main.py"
C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\bot\main.py:7: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\bot\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    mkButton = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[onclick^='fireLoginOrRegisterModalRequest'][onclick*='login']").click()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 88, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 396, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 435, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.114)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00D35FD3+2187219]
    Ordinal0 [0x00CCE6D1+1763025]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BE3D40+802112]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C12C03+994307]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C089B3+952755]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C2CB8C+1100684]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C08394+951188]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C2CDA4+1101220]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C3CFC2+1167298]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C2C9A6+1100198]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C06F80+946048]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C07E76+949878]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00FD90C2+2721218]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00FCAAF0+2662384]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00DC137A+526458]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00DC0416+522518]
    Ordinal0 [0x00CD4EAB+1789611]
    Ordinal0 [0x00CD97A8+1808296]
    Ordinal0 [0x00CD9895+1808533]
    Ordinal0 [0x00CE26C1+1844929]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7688FA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77D57A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77D57A6E+238]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as ***Mein Konto*** you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *partial_link_text*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Mein Konto").click()
  ```
- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[onclick^='fireLoginOrRegisterModalRequest'][onclick*='login']").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@onclick, 'fireLoginOrRegisterModalRequest') and contains(., 'Mein Konto')]").click()
  ```

---

Ideally to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Mein Konto"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[onclick^='fireLoginOrRegisterModalRequest'][onclick*='login']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@onclick, 'fireLoginOrRegisterModalRequest') and contains(., 'Mein Konto')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work with it. See the following error message

`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

first add `id` attribute for `<a>` tag

```
id="link"
```

then use the following:

```
# import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
  
# create webdriver object
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  
# get geeksforgeeks.org
driver.get("https://your.website.com")
  
# get element 
element = driver.find_element_by_id("link")
  
# click the element
element.click()
```

---

or just by the text

```
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Mein Konto")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following xpath -

```
//a[contains(@onclick,'fireLoginOrRegisterModalRequest('sign_in')')][contains(text(),'Mein Konto')]
```

The code will look like -

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@onclick,'fireLoginOrRegisterModalRequest('sign_in')')][contains(text(),'Mein Konto')]")
```

Let me know if this works.